# Redirect to router when i load a website on my directadmin server network

Tags: networking, server, dns, directadmin

I have a server in my office that connected to my ADSL router,
And I using this modem to my internet connection
My Server is HP DL380 With CentOs 7 + Directadmin
The modem is D-link DSL-2750U
When I loading my DirectAdmin websites, I redirected to the modem 
what's wrong with this and why this has happened?
All Sites are good in the internet and no problem
I can see my websites only when I using a VPN
Thank you, guys!

[i show it in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFnzQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are trying to connect to a server located on your network. Since this works with a VPN this would almost certainly be a routing problem.

A few 'traceroutes' from your CentOS server to your wifi device would tell you where the traffic is failing. Here are some common issues that cause your routing problem.

1) CentOs server contains a subnet that overlaps the wifi network or vice versa. This doesn't work since the CentOS server believes the device on the wifi is on the same subnet when it isn't.

2) Cent OS server contains a default route other than to the D-link router (unlikely)

If you can't ping the CentOs server from your wifi device and these are not the issues please provide a network diagram that includes IP addresses and subnets or the wifi network, Server network, and VPN network.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I can ping to my centos server and I don't have any connectivity problem with this, but when I try to open my website ( www.mysite.com ) that are located on my centos server DirectAdmin, it's redirected to my router, I think maybe it's DNS problem.

Comment: `[root@server ~]# netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens33
SERVERIP   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33
SERVERIP  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH        0 0          0 ens33
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens33
[root@server ~]#
`

Comment: DNS could do this. try 192.168.1.1 from your webbroswer. You should either create a DNS for internal traffic and point your computers to it or you can change your routing. Do you have a loopback route to route traffic from inside your network to the external interface back to your server? are you natting correcting so traffic will route back to the router external interface from your centOS?

Comment: this issue https://serverfault.com/questions/55611/loopback-to-forwarded-public-ip-address-from-local-network-hairpin-nat also http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=16358.0